# c# linq lambda where not

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Im following [this](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-lambda-expression) tutorial about lambda expressions, and created the following code;

```
Func<int, bool> isHighNUmber = s => s > 10;
IList<int> intList = new List<int>() { 1, 3,9, 2, 63, 236, 32, 474, 83, 832, 58, 3458, 35, 8, 4 };

Console.WriteLine("All numbers.");
foreach (int x in intList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
Console.WriteLine("High Numbers");
foreach(int x in intList.Where(isHighNUmber).ToList<int>())
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

And it works fine, now I wanted to try to get the low numbers only, so I tried

```
foreach(int x in intList.Where(!isHighNUmber).ToList<int>())

foreach(int x in intList.Where(isHighNUmber == false).ToList<int>())
```

and variations of the above syntax but could not get it to work. I also looked for a function like WhereNot

```
foreach(int x in intList.WhereNot(!isHighNUmber).ToList<int>())
```

to replace the where function but could not find a suitable one.I could easily add another Func to do the opposite of isHighNumber but I imagine if that func is very big you would not want to rewrite it completely. How should I get the opposite of a lambda Func in the where method?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
  foreach(int x in intList.Where(x=> !isHighNUmber(x)).ToList<int>())
```

You cannot use this syntactic sugar unless you create `isNotHighNumber` function that negates `isHighNumber`

Answer (score 0):

I think your only option in that case is to actually invoke the function

```
foreach (int x in intList.Where(x=>! isHighNUmber(x)).ToList<int>())
{
     Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Comment: "Actually invoke"? The method is also invoked when using `Where(IsHighNumber)`,  it´s just a shortcut for `Where(x => x.IsHighNumber(x))`.

Comment: maybe explicitly invoke is is a better description

Comment: @MiniverCheevy But you're not invoking it.  You're creating a new method whose body invokes it.

Comment: @HimBromBeere technically not a shortcut.  `Where` takes a delegate and that's what `IsHighNumber` already is, where as `x => IsHighNumber(x)` is a different delegate that wraps `IsHighNumber`

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `Except` but it would not be as efficient since it would likely iterate over the sequence twice.

```
Console.WriteLine("Low Numbers");
foreach (int x in intList.Except(intList.Where(isHighNUmber)).ToList<int>())
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should update your `Func` as shown below:

```
Func<int, bool, bool> isHighNUmber = (s, isGreaterCheck) => { return isGreaterCheck ? s > 10 :  s <= 10 ;};
```

and then write `foreach` as mentioned below:

```
Console.WriteLine("Low Numbers");
foreach(int x in intList.Where(x => isHighNUmber(x, false)).ToList<int>())
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Comment: `s < 10` is not the opposite of `s > 10`, maybe you meant `s <= 10`?